# Comparing three C++ data structures for discrete sampling with probability distributions

Tags: c++, algorithm, comparative-review, random

## Introduction

A probability distribution data structures receives pairs \$\langle e_i, w_i \rangle_{i = 1}^n\$, (\$e_i\$ is an element and \$w_i\$ is its respective positive weight) and provides a method for sampling random elements taking weights into account. If the data structure contains \$\langle A, 1.0 \rangle\$, \$\langle B, 1.0 \rangle\$ and \$\langle C, 3.0 \rangle\$, whenever we sample a random element, \$A\$ may be returned with probability \$0.2\$, \$B\$ may be returned with probability \$0.2\$, and \$C\$ may be returned with probability \$0.6\$. Formally, the sampling probability of \$e_i\$ is
$$P(e_i | w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n) = \frac{w_i}{\sum_{j = 1}^n w_j}.$$

## Code

**ProbabilityDistribution.hpp**

```
#ifndef NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP
#define NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP

#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace net {
namespace coderodde {
namespace util {

    template<typename T>
    class ProbabilityDistribution {
    public:
        ProbabilityDistribution(std::random_device::result_type seed)
        :
        m_size{0},
        m_total_weight{0.0},
        m_generator{seed},
        m_real_distribution{0.0, 1.0}
        {}

        ProbabilityDistribution()
        :
        m_size{0},
        m_total_weight{0.0},
        m_generator{},
        m_real_distribution{0.0, 1.0}
        {}

        virtual bool is_empty() const {
            return m_size == 0;
        }

        virtual size_t size() const {
            return m_size;
        }

        virtual bool add_element     (T const& element, double weight) = 0;
        virtual T    sample_element  ()                                = 0;
        virtual bool contains_element(T const& element)          const = 0;
        virtual bool remove_element  (T const& element)                = 0;
        virtual void clear           ()                                = 0;

    protected:

        size_t                                 m_size;
        double                                 m_total_weight;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> m_real_distribution;
        std::mt19937                           m_generator;

        void check_weight(double weight) {
            if (std::isnan(weight)) {
                throw std::invalid_argument("The input weight is NaN.");
            }

            if (weight <= 0.0) {
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << "The input weight is non-positive: " << weight << ".";
                throw std::invalid_argument(ss.str());
            }

            if (std::isinf(weight)) {
                throw std::invalid_argument(
                                    "The input weight is positive infinity.");
            }
        }

        void check_not_empty() const {
            if (is_empty()) {
                throw std::length_error{
                    "This probability distribution is empty."
                };
            }
        }
    };

} // End of namespace net::coderodde::util.
} // End of namespace net::coderodde.
} // End of namespace net.

#endif // NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP
```

**ArrayProbabilityDistribution.hpp**

```
#ifndef NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_ARRAY_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP
#define NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_ARRAY_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP

#include "ProbabilityDistribution.hpp"
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace net {
namespace coderodde {
namespace util {

    template<typename T>
    class ArrayProbabilityDistribution : public ProbabilityDistribution<T> {

    public:
        ArrayProbabilityDistribution() : ProbabilityDistribution<T>() {}
        ArrayProbabilityDistribution(std::random_device::result_type seed) :
        ProbabilityDistribution<T>(seed) {}

        ArrayProbabilityDistribution(
            const ArrayProbabilityDistribution<T>& other) {
            this->m_size             = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight     = other.m_total_weight;
            m_element_storage_vector = other.m_element_storage_vector;
            m_weight_storage_vector  = other.m_weight_storage_vector;
            m_filter_set             = other.m_filter_set;
        }

        ArrayProbabilityDistribution(
            ArrayProbabilityDistribution<T>&& other) {
            this->m_size             = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight     = other.m_total_weight;
            m_element_storage_vector =
                std::move(other.m_element_storage_vector);

            m_weight_storage_vector  = std::move(other.m_weight_storage_vector);
            m_filter_set             = std::move(other.m_filter_set);

            other.m_size         = 0;
            other.m_total_weight = 0.0;
        }

        ArrayProbabilityDistribution& operator=(
            const ArrayProbabilityDistribution<T>& other) {
            this->m_size             = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight     = other.m_total_weight;
            m_element_storage_vector = other.m_element_storage_vector;
            m_weight_storage_vector  = other.m_weight_storage_vector;
            m_filter_set             = other.m_filter_set;
            return *this;
        }

        ArrayProbabilityDistribution& operator=(
            ArrayProbabilityDistribution<T>&& other) {
            if (this == &other) {
                return *this;
            }

            this->m_size         = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight = other.m_total_weight;

            m_element_storage_vector =
                std::move(other.m_element_storage_vector);

            m_weight_storage_vector = std::move(other.m_weight_storage_vector);
            m_filter_set            = std::move(other.m_filter_set);

            other.m_size         = 0;
            other.m_total_weight = 0.0;

            return *this;
        }

        bool is_empty() const {
            return this->m_size == 0;
        }

        virtual size_t size() const {
            return this->m_size;
        }

        virtual bool add_element(T const& element, double weight) {
            if (m_filter_set.find(element) != m_filter_set.cend()) {
                return false;
            }

            this->check_weight(weight);
            m_element_storage_vector.push_back(element);
            m_weight_storage_vector.push_back(weight);
            m_filter_set.insert(element);
            this->m_total_weight += weight;
            this->m_size++;
            return true;
        }

        virtual T sample_element() {
            this->check_not_empty();
            double value = this->m_real_distribution(this->m_generator) *
                           this->m_total_weight;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < this->m_size; ++i) {
                if (value < m_weight_storage_vector[i]) {
                    return m_element_storage_vector[i];
                }

                value -= m_weight_storage_vector[i];
            }

            throw std::logic_error{"Should not get here."};
        }

        virtual bool contains_element(T const& element) const {
            return m_filter_set.find(element) != m_filter_set.cend();
        }

        virtual bool remove_element(T const& element) {
            if (!contains_element(element)) {
                return false;
            }

            auto target_element_iterator =
            std::find(m_element_storage_vector.begin(),
                      m_element_storage_vector.end(),
                      element);

            size_t target_index =
            std::distance(m_element_storage_vector.begin(),
                          target_element_iterator);

            m_element_storage_vector.erase(target_element_iterator);

            auto target_weight_iterator = m_weight_storage_vector.begin();
            std::advance(target_weight_iterator, target_index);

            double weight = m_weight_storage_vector[target_index];
            m_weight_storage_vector.erase(target_weight_iterator);
            m_filter_set.erase(element);

            this->m_size--;
            this->m_total_weight -= weight;
            return true;
        }

        virtual void clear() {
            this->m_size = 0;
            this->m_total_weight = 0.0;
            m_element_storage_vector.clear();
            m_weight_storage_vector.clear();
            m_filter_set.clear();
        }

    private:
        std::vector<T>        m_element_storage_vector;
        std::vector<double>   m_weight_storage_vector;
        std::unordered_set<T> m_filter_set;
    };

} // End of namespace net::coderodde::util.
} // End of namespace net::coderodde.
} // End of namespace net.


#endif // NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_ARRAY_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP
```

**LinkedListProbabilityDistribution.hpp**

```
#ifndef NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_LINKED_LIST_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP
#define NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_LINKED_LIST_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP

#include "ProbabilityDistribution.hpp"
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

namespace net {
namespace coderodde {
namespace util {

    template<typename T>
    class LinkedListProbabilityDistribution :
    public ProbabilityDistribution<T> {

        class LinkedListNode {
        private:

            T               m_element;
            double          m_weight;
            LinkedListNode* m_prev_node;
            LinkedListNode* m_next_node;

        public:

            LinkedListNode(T element, double weight) {
                m_element = element;
                m_weight  = weight;
            }

            T get_element() const {
                return m_element;
            }

            double get_weight() const {
                return m_weight;
            }

            LinkedListNode* get_prev_linked_list_node() const {
                return m_prev_node;
            }

            LinkedListNode* get_next_linked_list_node() const {
                return m_next_node;
            }

            void set_prev_linked_list_node(LinkedListNode* node) {
                m_prev_node = node;
            }

            void set_next_linked_list_node(LinkedListNode* node) {
                m_next_node = node;
            }
        };

    public:
        LinkedListProbabilityDistribution()
        :
        ProbabilityDistribution<T>{},
        m_head{nullptr},
        m_tail{nullptr}
        {}

        LinkedListProbabilityDistribution(std::random_device::result_type seed)
        :
        ProbabilityDistribution<T>{seed},
        m_head{nullptr},
        m_tail{nullptr}
        {}

        LinkedListProbabilityDistribution(
            const LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<T>& other) {
            this->m_size             = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight     = other.m_total_weight;

            // Copy the internal linked list:
            copy_linked_list(other.m_head);
        }

        LinkedListProbabilityDistribution(
            LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<T>&& other) {
            this->m_size             = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight     = other.m_total_weight;
            m_map                    = std::move(other.m_map);
            m_head                   = other.m_head;
            m_tail                   = other.m_tail;

            other.m_size         = 0;
            other.m_total_weight = 0.0;
            other.m_head         = nullptr;
            other.m_tail         = nullptr;
        }

        LinkedListProbabilityDistribution& operator=(
            const LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<T>& other) {
            delete_linked_list();
            copy_linked_list(other.m_head);

            this->m_size         = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight = other.m_total_weight;
            return *this;
        }

        LinkedListProbabilityDistribution& operator=(
            LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<T>&& other) {
            if (this == &other) {
                return *this;
            }

            delete_linked_list();

            this->m_size         = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight = other.m_total_weight;
            this->m_head         = other.m_head;
            this->m_tail         = other.m_tail;
            this->m_map          = std::move(other.m_map);

            other.m_size         = 0;
            other.m_total_weight = 0.0;
            other.m_head         = nullptr;
            other.m_tail         = nullptr;

            return *this;
        }

        ~LinkedListProbabilityDistribution() {
            delete_linked_list();
        }

        virtual bool add_element(T const& element, double weight) {
            if (m_map.find(element) != m_map.end()) {
                return false;
            }

            this->check_weight(weight);
            LinkedListNode* new_node = new LinkedListNode{element, weight};

            if (m_head == nullptr) {
                m_head = new_node;
                m_tail = new_node;
                new_node->set_prev_linked_list_node(nullptr);
                new_node->set_next_linked_list_node(nullptr);
            } else {
                new_node->set_prev_linked_list_node(m_tail);
                new_node->set_next_linked_list_node(nullptr);
                m_tail->set_next_linked_list_node(new_node);
                m_tail = new_node;
            }

            m_map[element] = new_node;
            this->m_size++;
            this->m_total_weight += weight;
            return true;
        }

        virtual T sample_element() {
            this->check_not_empty();
            double value = this->m_real_distribution(this->m_generator) *
                           this->m_total_weight;

            for (LinkedListNode* node = m_head;
                 ;
                 node = node->get_next_linked_list_node()) {
                if (value < node->get_weight()) {
                    return node->get_element();
                }

                value -= node->get_weight();
            }

            throw std::logic_error{"Should not get here."};
        }

        virtual bool contains_element(T const& element) const {
            return m_map.find(element) != m_map.end();
        }

        virtual bool remove_element(T const& element) {
            if (!contains_element(element)) {
                return false;
            }

            LinkedListNode* node = m_map[element];

            m_map.erase(element);
            this->m_size--;
            this->m_total_weight -= node->get_weight();
            unlink(node);
            delete node;
            return true;
        }

        virtual void clear() {
            this->m_size = 0;
            this->m_total_weight = 0.0;
            m_map.clear();
            delete_linked_list();
            m_head = nullptr;
            m_tail = nullptr;
        }

    private:
        std::unordered_map<T, LinkedListNode*> m_map;
        LinkedListNode* m_head;
        LinkedListNode* m_tail;

        void unlink(LinkedListNode* node) {
            LinkedListNode* prev_node = node->get_prev_linked_list_node();
            LinkedListNode* next_node = node->get_next_linked_list_node();

            if (prev_node != nullptr) {
                prev_node->set_next_linked_list_node(
                     node->get_next_linked_list_node());
            } else {
                m_head = node->get_next_linked_list_node();

                if (m_head != nullptr) {
                    m_head->set_prev_linked_list_node(nullptr);
                }
            }

            if (next_node != nullptr) {
                next_node->set_prev_linked_list_node(
                     node->get_prev_linked_list_node());
            } else {
                m_tail = node->get_prev_linked_list_node();

                if (m_tail != nullptr) {
                    m_tail->set_next_linked_list_node(nullptr);
                }
            }
        }

        void delete_linked_list() {
            for (LinkedListNode* node = m_head, *next; node != nullptr;) {
                next = node->get_next_linked_list_node();
                delete node;
                node = next;
            }
        }

        void copy_linked_list(LinkedListNode* source_head) {
            if (source_head == nullptr) {
                m_head = nullptr;
                m_tail = nullptr;
                return;
            }

            m_head = m_tail = new LinkedListNode{source_head->get_element(),
                                                 source_head->get_weight()};

            m_head->set_prev_linked_list_node(nullptr);
            m_map[m_head->get_element()] = m_head;

            for (LinkedListNode* node =
                    source_head->get_next_linked_list_node();
                 node != nullptr;
                 node = node->get_next_linked_list_node()) {
                LinkedListNode* new_node =
                    new LinkedListNode(node->get_element(),
                                          node->get_weight());

                m_tail->set_next_linked_list_node(new_node);
                new_node->set_prev_linked_list_node(m_tail);
                m_tail = new_node;

                m_map[new_node->get_element()] = new_node;
            }

            m_tail->set_next_linked_list_node(nullptr);
        }
    };

} // End of namespace net::coderodde::util.
} // End of namespace net::coderodde.
} // End of namespace net.


#endif // NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_LINKED_LIST_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP
```

**BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution.hpp**

```
#ifndef NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_BINARY_TREE_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP
#define NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_BINARY_TREE_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP

#include "ProbabilityDistribution.hpp"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

namespace net {
namespace coderodde {
namespace util {

    template<typename T>
    class BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution :
    public ProbabilityDistribution<T> {
    private:

        class TreeNode {
        private:

            T         m_element;
            double    m_weight;
            bool      m_is_relay_node;
            TreeNode* m_left_child;
            TreeNode* m_right_child;
            TreeNode* m_parent;
            size_t    m_leaf_node_count;

        public:

            TreeNode(T element, double weight)
            :
            m_element{element},
            m_weight{weight},
            m_is_relay_node{false},
            m_leaf_node_count{1},
            m_left_child{nullptr},
            m_right_child{nullptr},
            m_parent{nullptr}
            {}

            TreeNode()
            :
            m_element{},
            m_weight{},
            m_is_relay_node{true},
            m_leaf_node_count{},
            m_left_child{nullptr},
            m_right_child{nullptr},
            m_parent{nullptr}
            {}

            T get_element() const {
                return m_element;
            }

            double get_weight() const {
                return m_weight;
            }

            void set_weight(double weight) {
                m_weight = weight;
            }

            size_t get_number_of_leaves() const {
                return m_leaf_node_count;
            }

            void set_number_of_leaves(size_t leaf_node_count) {
                m_leaf_node_count = leaf_node_count;
            }

            TreeNode* get_left_child() const {
                return m_left_child;
            }

            void set_left_child(TreeNode* node) {
                m_left_child = node;
            }

            TreeNode* get_right_child() const {
                return m_right_child;
            }

            void set_right_child(TreeNode* node) {
                m_right_child = node;
            }

            TreeNode* get_parent() const {
                return m_parent;
            }

            void set_parent(TreeNode* node) {
                m_parent = node;
            }

            bool is_relay_node() const {
                return m_is_relay_node;
            }

            bool is_leaf_node() const {
                return !m_is_relay_node;
            }
        };

    public:

        BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution()
        :
        BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution(std::random_device::result_type{})
        {}

        BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution(std::random_device::result_type seed)
        :
        ProbabilityDistribution<T>{seed},
        m_root{nullptr}
        {}

        BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution(
            const BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<T>& other) {
            this->m_size         = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight = other.m_total_weight;

            // Copy the internal tree:
            copy_tree(other.m_root);
        }

        BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution(
            BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<T>&& other) {
            this->m_size         = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight = other.m_total_weight;

            m_map  = std::move(other.m_map);
            m_root = other.m_root;

            other.m_size         = 0;
            other.m_total_weight = 0.0;
            other.m_root         = nullptr;
        }

        BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution& operator=(
            const BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<T>& other) {
            if (this == &other) {
                return *this;
            }

            delete_tree();
            copy_tree(other.m_root);

            this->m_size         = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight = other.m_total_weight;
            return *this;
        }

        BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution& operator=(
            BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<T>&& other) {
            if (this == &other) {
                return *this;
            }

            delete_tree();

            this->m_size         = other.m_size;
            this->m_total_weight = other.m_total_weight;
            this->m_root         = other.m_root;
            this->m_map          = std::move(other.m_map);

            other.m_size         = 0;
            other.m_total_weight = 0.0;
            other.m_root         = nullptr;

            return *this;
        }

        virtual bool add_element(T const& element, double weight) {
            if (m_map.find(element) != m_map.end()) {
                return false;
            }

            this->check_weight(weight);
            TreeNode* new_node = new TreeNode{element, weight};
            insert(new_node);
            this->m_size++;
            this->m_total_weight += weight;
            m_map[element] = new_node;
            return true;
        }

        virtual bool contains_element(T const& element) const {
            return m_map.find(element) != m_map.end();
        }

        virtual T sample_element() {
            this->check_not_empty();
            double value = this->m_real_distribution(this->m_generator) *
                           this->m_total_weight;

            TreeNode* node = m_root;

            while (node->is_relay_node()) {
                if (value < node->get_left_child()->get_weight()) {
                    node = node->get_left_child();
                } else {
                    value -= node->get_left_child()->get_weight();
                    node = node->get_right_child();
                }
            }

            return node->get_element();
        }

        virtual bool remove_element(T const& element) {
            if (!contains_element(element)) {
                return false;
            }

            TreeNode* node = m_map[element];
            delete_node(node);
            m_map.erase(element);
            update_metadata(node->get_parent(), -node->get_weight(), -1);
            this->m_size--;
            this->m_total_weight -= node->get_weight();
            return true;
        }

        virtual void clear() {
            delete_tree();
            m_map.clear();

            m_root               = nullptr;
            this->m_size         = 0;
            this->m_total_weight = 0.0;
        }

    private:

        void delete_node(TreeNode* node) {
            TreeNode* relay_node = node->get_parent();

            if (relay_node == nullptr) {
                m_root = nullptr;
                return;
            }

            TreeNode* parent_of_relay_node = relay_node->get_parent();
            TreeNode* sibling_leaf = relay_node->get_left_child() == node ?
                                     relay_node->get_right_child() :
                                     relay_node->get_left_child();

            if (parent_of_relay_node == nullptr) {
                m_root = sibling_leaf;
                sibling_leaf->set_parent(nullptr);
                return;
            }

            if (parent_of_relay_node->get_left_child() == relay_node) {
                parent_of_relay_node->set_left_child(sibling_leaf);
            } else {
                parent_of_relay_node->set_right_child(sibling_leaf);
            }

            sibling_leaf->set_parent(parent_of_relay_node);
        }

        void update_metadata(TreeNode* node,
                             double weight_delta,
                             size_t node_count_delta) {
            while (node != nullptr) {
                node->set_number_of_leaves(
                            node->get_number_of_leaves() + node_count_delta);
                node->set_weight(node->get_weight() + weight_delta);
                node = node->get_parent();
            }
        }

        void bypass_leaf_node(TreeNode* bypass_node, TreeNode* new_node) {
            TreeNode* relay_node = new TreeNode{};
            TreeNode* parent_of_current_node = bypass_node->get_parent();

            relay_node->set_number_of_leaves(1);
            relay_node->set_weight(bypass_node->get_weight());
            relay_node->set_left_child(bypass_node);
            relay_node->set_right_child(new_node);

            bypass_node->set_parent(relay_node);
            new_node->set_parent(relay_node);

            if (parent_of_current_node == nullptr) {
                m_root = relay_node;
            } else if (parent_of_current_node->get_left_child()
                       == bypass_node) {
                relay_node->set_parent(parent_of_current_node);
                parent_of_current_node->set_left_child(relay_node);
            } else {
                relay_node->set_parent(parent_of_current_node);
                parent_of_current_node->set_right_child(relay_node);
            }

            update_metadata(relay_node, new_node->get_weight(), 1);
        }

        void insert(TreeNode* new_node) {
            if (m_root == nullptr) {
                m_root = new_node;
                new_node->set_parent(nullptr);
                new_node->set_left_child(nullptr);
                new_node->set_right_child(nullptr);
                return;
            }

            TreeNode* current_node = m_root;

            while (current_node->is_relay_node()) {
                if (current_node->get_left_child()->get_number_of_leaves() <
                    current_node->get_right_child()->get_number_of_leaves()) {
                    current_node = current_node->get_left_child();
                } else {
                    current_node = current_node->get_right_child();
                }
            }

            bypass_leaf_node(current_node, new_node);
        }

        void delete_tree(TreeNode* node) {
            if (node == nullptr) {
                return;
            }

            delete_tree(node->get_left_child());
            delete_tree(node->get_right_child());
            delete node;
        }

        void delete_tree() {
            delete_tree(m_root);
            m_root = nullptr;
        }

        TreeNode* copy_tree_impl(TreeNode* node) {
            if (node == nullptr) {
                return nullptr;
            }

            TreeNode* new_node = new TreeNode{node->get_element(),
                                              node->get_weight()};

            m_map[new_node->get_element()] = new_node;

            new_node->set_left_child (copy_tree_impl(node->get_left_child()));
            new_node->set_right_child(copy_tree_impl(node->get_right_child()));
            return new_node;
        }

        void copy_tree(TreeNode* copy_root) {
            m_root = copy_tree_impl(copy_root);
        }

        std::unordered_map<T, TreeNode*> m_map;
        TreeNode* m_root;
    };

} // End of namespace net::coderodde::util.
} // End of namespace net::coderodde.
} // End of namespace net.

#endif // NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_BINARY_TREE_PROBABILITY_DISTRIBUTION_HPP
```

**assert.hpp**

```
#ifndef ASSERT_HPP
#define ASSERT_HPP

#include <iostream>

#define ASSERT(CONDITION) assert(CONDITION, #CONDITION, __FILE__, __LINE__);
#define REPORT            assert.report();
#define TOTAL_ASSERTIONS  assert.get_total_number_of_assertions()
#define FAILED_ASSERTIONS assert.get_number_of_failed_assertions()
#define FAIL(MSG)         assert.fail(MSG)

class Assert {
public:
    bool operator()(const bool condition,
                    const char *const condition_text,
                    const char *const file_name,
                    const int line_number);

    size_t get_total_number_of_assertions() const;
    size_t get_number_of_failed_assertions() const;
    void fail(const char* msg);
    void report() const;

private:
    size_t m_total_assertions;
    size_t m_failed_assertions;
};

// Can't think of anything better than a global.
extern Assert assert;

#endif  // ASSERT_HPP
```

**assert.cpp**

```
#include "assert.hpp"
#include <iostream>

bool Assert::operator()(const bool condition,
                        const char *const condition_text,
                        const char *const file_name,
                        const int line_number) {
    if (!condition) {
        m_failed_assertions++;
        std::cerr << "'" << condition_text << "' is not true in file "
        << "'" << file_name << "' at line " << line_number << "."
        << std::endl;
    }

    m_total_assertions++;
    return condition;
}

size_t Assert::get_number_of_failed_assertions() const {
    return m_failed_assertions;
}

size_t Assert::get_total_number_of_assertions() const {
    return m_total_assertions;
}

void Assert::fail(const char *msg) {
    std::cerr << "FAILURE: " << msg << '\n';
    m_failed_assertions++;
}

void Assert::report() const {
    std::cout << "[TOTAL ASSERTIONS: "
    << m_total_assertions
    << ", FAILED ASSERTIONS: "
    << m_failed_assertions
    << ", PASS RATIO: ";

    if (m_total_assertions == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "N/A";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << ((float)
                      (m_total_assertions - m_failed_assertions)) / m_total_assertions;
    }

    std::cout << "]";

    if (m_failed_assertions == 0) {
        std::cout << " Test success!\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << " Some tests failed.\n";
    }
}

Assert assert;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "ArrayProbabilityDistribution.hpp"
#include "BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution.hpp"
#include "LinkedListProbabilityDistribution.hpp"
#include "ProbabilityDistribution.hpp"
#include "assert.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using net::coderodde::util::ProbabilityDistribution;
using net::coderodde::util::ArrayProbabilityDistribution;
using net::coderodde::util::BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution;
using net::coderodde::util::LinkedListProbabilityDistribution;

static void test_all();
static void demo();
static void benchmark();

int main() {
    demo();
    benchmark();
    test_all();
    REPORT
}

static void test_array();
static void test_linked_list();
static void test_tree();

static void test_all() {
    test_array();
    test_linked_list();
    test_tree();
}

static void test_impl(ProbabilityDistribution<int>* dist) {
    ASSERT(dist->is_empty());

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist->size() == i);
        dist->add_element(i, 1.0);
        ASSERT(dist->size() == i + 1);
    }

    ASSERT(dist->is_empty() == false);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist->contains_element(i));
    }

    ASSERT(dist->contains_element(-1) == false);

    for (int i = 4; i < 10; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist->contains_element(i) == false);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist->add_element(i, 2.0) == false);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist->remove_element(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist->remove_element(i) == false);
    }

    try {
        dist->sample_element();
        FAIL("std::length_error expected.");
    } catch (std::length_error err) {}

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        dist->add_element(i, 2.0);
    }

    ASSERT(dist->size() == 4);
    dist->clear();
    ASSERT(dist->size() == 0);
}

static void test_array() {
    test_impl(new ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int>);

    ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int> dist1;
    ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int> dist2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        dist2.add_element(i, 1.0);
    }

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 0);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 3);

    dist1 = dist2;

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 3);

    ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int> dist3(dist1);

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist3.size() == 3);

    ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int> dist4;
    dist4 = std::move(dist1);

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 0);
    ASSERT(dist4.size() == 3);

    ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int> dist5(std::move(dist2));

    ASSERT(dist5.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 0);

    dist1.clear();
    dist2.clear();

    ASSERT(dist1.is_empty());
    ASSERT(dist2.is_empty());

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i) {
        dist1.add_element(i, 1.5);
    }

    // Test move assignment:
    dist2 = std::move(dist1);

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist2.contains_element(i));
        ASSERT(dist1.contains_element(i) == false);
    }

    // Test move constructor:
    ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int> dist6(std::move(dist2));

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist6.contains_element(i));
        ASSERT(dist2.contains_element(i) == false);
    }

    // Test copy constructor:
    ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int> dist7(dist6);
    dist7.remove_element(14);

    for (int i = 10; i < 14; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist6.contains_element(i));
        ASSERT(dist7.contains_element(i));
    }

    ASSERT(dist6.contains_element(14));
    ASSERT(dist7.contains_element(14) == false);

    ASSERT(dist6.size() == 5);
    ASSERT(dist7.size() == 4);

    // Test copy assignment:
    dist1.clear();
    dist1 = dist6;

    ASSERT(dist6.size() == 5);
    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 5);

    ASSERT(dist1.remove_element(11));
    ASSERT(dist1.remove_element(13));

    ASSERT(dist6.size() == 5);
    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 3);
}

static void test_linked_list() {
    test_impl(new LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int>);

    LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int> dist1;
    LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int> dist2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        dist2.add_element(i, 1.0);
    }

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 0);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 3);

    dist1 = dist2;

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 3);

    LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int> dist3(dist1);

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist3.size() == 3);

    LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int> dist4;
    dist4 = std::move(dist1);

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 0);
    ASSERT(dist4.size() == 3);

    LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int> dist5(std::move(dist2));

    ASSERT(dist5.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 0);

    dist1.clear();
    dist2.clear();

    ASSERT(dist1.is_empty());
    ASSERT(dist2.is_empty());

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i) {
        dist1.add_element(i, 1.5);
    }

    // Test move assignment:
    dist2 = std::move(dist1);

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist2.contains_element(i));
        ASSERT(dist1.contains_element(i) == false);
    }

    // Test move constructor:
    LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int> dist6(std::move(dist2));

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist6.contains_element(i));
        ASSERT(dist2.contains_element(i) == false);
    }

    // Test copy constructor:
    LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int> dist7(dist6);
    dist7.remove_element(14);

    for (int i = 10; i < 14; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist6.contains_element(i));
        ASSERT(dist7.contains_element(i));
    }

    ASSERT(dist6.contains_element(14));
    ASSERT(dist7.contains_element(14) == false);

    ASSERT(dist6.size() == 5);
    ASSERT(dist7.size() == 4);

    // Test copy assignment:
    dist1.clear();
    dist1 = dist6;

    ASSERT(dist6.size() == 5);
    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 5);

    ASSERT(dist1.remove_element(11));
    ASSERT(dist1.remove_element(13));

    ASSERT(dist6.size() == 5);
    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 3);

}

static void test_tree() {
    test_impl(new BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int>);


    BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int> dist1;
    BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int> dist2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        dist2.add_element(i, 1.0);
    }

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 0);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 3);

    dist1 = dist2;

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 3);

    BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int> dist3(dist1);

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist3.size() == 3);

    BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int> dist4;
    dist4 = std::move(dist1);

    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 0);
    ASSERT(dist4.size() == 3);

    BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int> dist5(std::move(dist2));

    ASSERT(dist5.size() == 3);
    ASSERT(dist2.size() == 0);

    dist1.clear();
    dist2.clear();

    ASSERT(dist1.is_empty());
    ASSERT(dist2.is_empty());

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i) {
        dist1.add_element(i, 1.5);
    }

    // Test move assignment:
    dist2 = std::move(dist1);

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist2.contains_element(i));
        ASSERT(dist1.contains_element(i) == false);
    }

    // Test move constructor:
    BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int> dist6(std::move(dist2));

    for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist6.contains_element(i));
        ASSERT(dist2.contains_element(i) == false);
    }

    // Test copy constructor:
    BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int> dist7(dist6);
    dist7.remove_element(14);

    for (int i = 10; i < 14; ++i) {
        ASSERT(dist6.contains_element(i));
        ASSERT(dist7.contains_element(i));
    }

    ASSERT(dist6.contains_element(14));
    ASSERT(dist7.contains_element(14) == false);

    ASSERT(dist6.size() == 5);
    ASSERT(dist7.size() == 4);

    // Test copy assignment:
    dist1.clear();
    dist1 = dist6;

    ASSERT(dist6.size() == 5);
    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 5);

    ASSERT(dist1.remove_element(11));
    ASSERT(dist1.remove_element(13));

    ASSERT(dist6.size() == 5);
    ASSERT(dist1.size() == 3);
}

static void demo() {
    std::cout << "--- Sanity demo ---\n";

    using net::coderodde::util::ArrayProbabilityDistribution;
    using net::coderodde::util::LinkedListProbabilityDistribution;
    using net::coderodde::util::BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution;

    std::random_device rd{};
    std::random_device::result_type seed = rd();

    ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int> prob_dist1{seed};
    LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int> prob_dist2{seed};
    BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int> prob_dist3{seed};

    prob_dist1.add_element(1, 1.0);
    prob_dist1.add_element(2, 1.0);
    prob_dist1.add_element(3, 3.0);

    prob_dist2.add_element(1, 1.0);
    prob_dist2.add_element(2, 1.0);
    prob_dist2.add_element(3, 3.0);

    prob_dist3.add_element(1, 1.0);
    prob_dist3.add_element(2, 1.0);
    prob_dist3.add_element(3, 3.0);

    int arr1[4] = {};
    int arr2[4] = {};
    int arr3[4] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        arr1[prob_dist1.sample_element()]++;
        arr2[prob_dist2.sample_element()]++;
        arr3[prob_dist3.sample_element()]++;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr2[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr3[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n-------------------\n";
}

static size_t LOAD = 40 * 1000;
static size_t SAMPLES = 40 * 1000;

static void benchmark() {

    class CurrentTime {
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock m_clock;

    public:
        uint64_t milliseconds() {
            return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
            (m_clock.now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        }
    };

    ArrayProbabilityDistribution<int>      prob_dist1;
    LinkedListProbabilityDistribution<int> prob_dist2;
    BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution<int> prob_dist3;

    std::vector<int> remove_order_vector;

    for (int i = 0; i < LOAD; ++i) {
        remove_order_vector.push_back(i);
    }
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::shuffle(remove_order_vector.begin(),
                 remove_order_vector.end(),
                 g);

    CurrentTime ct;

    //// ARRAY BASED BENCHMARK ////
    std::cout << "ArrayProbabilityDistribution:\n";

    uint64_t add_time = 0;
    uint64_t sample_time = 0;
    uint64_t remove_time = 0;

    uint64_t start = ct.milliseconds();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < LOAD; ++i) {
        prob_dist1.add_element(i, 1.0);
    }

    uint64_t end = ct.milliseconds();

    add_time = end - start;
    std::cout << "  add_element: " << add_time << " milliseconds.\n";

    start = ct.milliseconds();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SAMPLES; ++i) {
        prob_dist1.sample_element();
    }

    end = ct.milliseconds();

    sample_time = end - start;
    std::cout << "  sample_element: " << sample_time << " milliseconds.\n";

    start = ct.milliseconds();

    for (int element : remove_order_vector) {
        prob_dist1.remove_element(element);
    }

    end = ct.milliseconds();

    remove_time = end - start;
    std::cout << "  remove_element: " << remove_time << " milliseconds.\n";
    std::cout << "  Total: " << (add_time + sample_time + remove_time)
              << " milliseconds.\n";


    //// LINKED LIST BASED BENCHMARK ////
    std::cout << "LinkedListProbabilityDistribution:\n";

    add_time = 0;
    sample_time = 0;
    remove_time = 0;

    start = ct.milliseconds();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < LOAD; ++i) {
        prob_dist2.add_element(i, 1.0);
    }

    end = ct.milliseconds();

    add_time = end - start;
    std::cout << "  add_element: " << add_time << " milliseconds.\n";

    start = ct.milliseconds();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SAMPLES; ++i) {
        prob_dist2.sample_element();
    }

    end = ct.milliseconds();

    sample_time = end - start;
    std::cout << "  sample_element: " << sample_time << " milliseconds.\n";

    start = ct.milliseconds();

    for (int element : remove_order_vector) {
        prob_dist2.remove_element(element);
    }

    end = ct.milliseconds();

    remove_time = end - start;
    std::cout << "  remove_element: " << remove_time << " milliseconds.\n";
    std::cout << "  Total: " << (add_time + sample_time + remove_time)
    << " milliseconds.\n";

    //// TREE BASED BENCHMARK ////
    std::cout << "BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution:\n";

    add_time = 0;
    sample_time = 0;
    remove_time = 0;

    start = ct.milliseconds();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < LOAD; ++i) {
        prob_dist3.add_element(i, 1.0);
    }

    end = ct.milliseconds();

    add_time = end - start;
    std::cout << "  add_element: " << add_time << " milliseconds.\n";

    start = ct.milliseconds();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SAMPLES; ++i) {
        prob_dist3.sample_element();
    }

    end = ct.milliseconds();

    sample_time = end - start;
    std::cout << "  sample_element: " << sample_time << " milliseconds.\n";

    start = ct.milliseconds();

    for (int element : remove_order_vector) {
        prob_dist3.remove_element(element);
    }

    end = ct.milliseconds();

    remove_time = end - start;
    std::cout << "  remove_element: " << remove_time << " milliseconds.\n";
    std::cout << "  Total: " << (add_time + sample_time + remove_time)
    << " milliseconds.\n";
}
```

## Benchmark

My benchmark prints this:

> ```
> --- Sanity demo ---
> 192 223 585 
> 192 223 585 
> 192 223 585 
> -------------------
> ArrayProbabilityDistribution:
>   add_element: 9 milliseconds.
>   sample_element: 1365 milliseconds.
>   remove_element: 707 milliseconds.
>   Total: 2081 milliseconds.
> LinkedListProbabilityDistribution:
>   add_element: 8 milliseconds.
>   sample_element: 3758 milliseconds.
>   remove_element: 16 milliseconds.
>   Total: 3782 milliseconds.
> BinaryTreeProbabilityDistribution:
>   add_element: 29 milliseconds.
>   sample_element: 27 milliseconds.
>   remove_element: 36 milliseconds.
>   Total: 92 milliseconds.
> [TOTAL ASSERTIONS: 258, FAILED ASSERTIONS: 0, PASS RATIO: 1] Test success!
> Program ended with exit code: 0
> ```

## Critique request

Please tell me anything that comes to mind. However, I am most concerned with adherence to C++ programming idioms.

Comment: Is this intended to be a replacement for [`std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution)?

Comment: @Edward Oh man, I have never heard of it, so the `reinventing-the-wheel` tag would be in order.

Comment: @Edward, wow, I guess `<random>` header is vastly unexplored on this site. I've never seen it too.

Comment: @Edward @Incomputable It's faster than even the binary tree distribution which runs all operations in logarithmic time. The weakness of `std::discrete_distribution` is the fact that it does not support non-integer template parameters and the removal operation. I suspect it uses some algorithm running in \$\mathcal{O}(\log \log n)\$ time from Knuth's TAOCP.

Comment: @coderodde, it returns integers which you can use to `std::next(container.cbegin(), distribution());`, writing up an answer now.

Comment: @coderodde, by the way, isn't it like generating a number in [1, sum of all weights] and then choosing into which range it gets? My knowledge of math is very limited, but that is my first guess. I'd also like to implement the class I proposed myself. Will post it by tomorrow.

Comment: @Incomputable Yes, but rather we "toss a coin" in \$[0, sum)\$ and look in what "bucket" the coin goes.

Comment: Is ability to add new elements necessary? Without it, the code fits 20-35 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Concept review

I had some controversial thoughts, but now it is all clear, after @Edward have provided the link to the `std::discrete_distribution`. So I'll mostly compare the code in the post with the distribution.

### Multiple concerns

Current code does lifetime management and discrete distribution logic. I guess one could use something like this:

```
template <typename Container, typename PredefinedGenerator>
class discrete_select // ?
{
    //other members
    //insert check for difference type here
    std::discrete_distribution<typename Container::const_iterator::difference_type> distribution;
public:
    template <typename GeneratorArgs>
    discrete_select(const Container& container, 
                    std::initializer_list<double> weights, 
                    GeneratorArgs&& ... args): 
    //initialize container and forward args to generator
    {} 

    const_iterator operator()()
    {
        return std::next(container.cbegin(), distribution());
    }
}
```

*(the ? means that I'm not sure if it is mathematically correct name)*

`PredefinedGenerator` might be unnecessary here.

- It delegates resource management to container, yet it holds ownership of it. I believe this is better because covering all of the container types is impossible. This also provides insane flexibility.
- The decision to use `PredefinedGenerator` lies in rule of 3 of them. If I'm not mistaken, all of them support rule of 3.
- It will have flexibility to provide range like objects. I believe @Emily have shown a "decorator" range, e.g. it returns an object which has `begin()` and `end()`, but does somewhat different behavior than original container. If container is stored by const, the need to call `cbegin()` is lifted.
- I guess this will cause insane code decrease. I'd bet it will be around 3 to 5 times.

### Code Review

```
        if (std::isnan(weight)) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("The input weight is NaN.");
        }
```

I'm not sure if it is gonna be useful to check for it. I guess they have much bigger problems if they have `NaN`, so I guess it would be better to remove the check, and document that `NaN` is not valid input argument.

Formatting. May be it is subjective, but it is harder to read for me. I need to do more head movement. People with bad vision will probably have bigger problems.

Raw pointers. I know only of two possible cases where smart pointers would lead to stack overflow:

1. Linked list with too many elements.
2. Graph -- easy to cause inifinite loop if implemented wrong. Harder to implement with smart pointers (in my opinion).

I guess the code is not made to handle linked lists with many elements (10^5 and up). The other one is a tree, which has nice top-down ownership semantics.

Subjective, but I think that using `std::istringstream` is overkill for error generation. `std::to_string()` could be used and the string could be concatenated. Though I wouldn't be surprised if compiler figured that out. Especially since number of inlinings in one scope is three for clang as of 2016, I believe.

Comment: I'm not in a good shape these days, so if you find anything suspicious please comment on it. If you think it is wrong, it probably is.

Comment: No problem. I will take a look soon.